# Ionic 2 Unknown platforms: –-release, –-prod error

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have run "**ionic build android --release --prod**" and some process then return "**Error: Unknown platforms: –-release, –-prod**" error.

I have build ionic 2 application in android **release + production**. How it possible?

**Note:** I have all-ready fire "**ionic platform add android**" this command.

Comment: have you added the platform?

Comment: YES............

Comment: ok.. just need to confirm the obvious question.. you should add all relevant details to the question as well

Comment: i am fire --release app command means. i have developed application and testing this application. i haven't run application without add platform.

Comment: what is the output of `ionic info`?

Comment: I'm also facing same issue.. below is the result of ionic info:
  ordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 7
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. When I had this problem I removed the application platforms and added the string again and it worked.